# Error while submitting form in Django. ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, django

I can't get the following problem solved even with the answers to related questions on this site.

At the moment I am doing the Django tutorial but got stuck with the form.
The following error, that i get whem submitting a favorite song, is bugging me:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I tried everything i could think of (e.g. `selected_song = album.song_set.get(pk= int(request.POST['song'])`) and googled looking for an answer but i can't seem to fix it. I appreciate any help.

**detail.html**

```
<form action="{%  url 'music:favorite' album.id %}" method = "post">
    {%  csrf_token %}
    {% for song in album.song_set.all %}
        <input type = "radio" id = "song{{ forloop.counter }}" name = "song" value = "{{ song_id }}" /> 
        <label for="song{{ forloop.counter }}">
            {{ song.song_title }}
            {% if song.is_favorite %}
                <img src="http://http://i.imgur.com/b9b13Rd.png" />
            {% endif %}
        </label><br>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Favorite">
</form>
```

views.py

```
def favorite(request, album_id):
    album = get_object_or_404(Album, pk = album_id)
    try:
        selected_song = album.song_set.get(pk= int(request.POST['song']))
    except (KeyError, Song.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'music/detail.html', {
            'album':album,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a valid song"
            })
    else:
        selected_song.is_favorite = True
        selected_song.save()
        return render(request, 'music/detail.html', {'album': album})
```

Comment: Please provide the trackback of your exception. Also have you tried to check what's the value for `request.POST['song']`?

Comment: An empty value is being sent to your view, so it is trying to cast '' to an int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your template you are doing

```
<input type = "radio" id = "song{{ forloop.counter }}" name = "song" value = "{{ song_id }}" />
```

`{{song_id}}` is `None` in this case. You need to use `{{song.id}}`.

```
<input type = "radio" id = "song{{ forloop.counter }}" name = "song" value = "{{ song.id }}" />
```

So a blank string `''` is passed to your view, which you are trying to pass to `int` hence the error.